# freeze columns while moving horizontally and freeze header while moving vertically in gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want to freeze two columns while moving horizontally and freeze header while moving vertically in gridview.
I have tried a [jquery plugin](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/). But it is not working.In this jquery plugin 
table is used and i have used gridview.In this jquery plugin gridview is binded on page load and i have to bind 
gridview on button click.My Gridview takes 6-7 minutes to bind

```
  protected void OnGV_ServicesDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
                gv_services.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
                row.CssClass = "GridviewScrollHeader";      
        }


      protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
       {          
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    e.Row.CssClass = "GridviewScrollItem"; 
                }      
        }

      <asp:GridView ID="gv_services" runat="server" CellPadding="3" CssClass="grid" Width="100%"
      OnDataBound="OnGV_ServicesDataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
      EnableViewState="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableTheming="True">
      <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" CssClass="GridviewScrollItem" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="40px" CssClass="GridviewScrollHeader" />                   
      <Columns>                  
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Services" DataField="Services" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3"
      ItemStyle-Width="300px">
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#089DE3"></HeaderStyle>
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="Category" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3"
      ItemStyle-Width="300px">
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#089DE3"></HeaderStyle>
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CPTs" DataField="CPTs" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#089de3"
      ItemStyle-Width="300px">
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#089DE3"></HeaderStyle>
      </asp:BoundField>
      </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```